# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Тут она уступает керамической арматуре(,) и даже гуммированной (или шланговой) —  в зависимости от условий применения. Что-то у меня заскок. Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Прошу прощения, керамическая арматура, да и гуммированная, для меня ново и интересно. Можете ссылочку дать?

Answer (score 1):

Если союз "и" употребляется в присоединительном значении "и притом", то запятая ставится. В данном случае значение "и притом" присутствует, следовательно, запятая нужна

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Вам в помощь. http://www.konorama.ru/igry/zapatan/

Comment: А можете аргументировать как-то?

Comment: Во-первых , это простое предложение, во-вторых союз и присоединяет частицу даже( после которой запятая не ставится).

Answer (score 0):

Перед *даже*, по моему мнению, запятая ставится всегда — присутствует некий оттенок присоединения, добавления.

К примеру, я придумал такое предложение:

> Все, даже Пётр, пришли на вечеринку.

А вот насчёт Вашего предложения я, к досаде, ничто не могу сказать.

Хотите почитать подробно — используйте этот материал: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_148

Comment: @Tagirix, запятая после "даже" ставится в том случае, если " даже" является союзом.

Comment: В вашем предложении два разных субъекта, поэтому запятая нужна. Измените ваше предложение, запятая не нужна будет. Ср. :На вечеринку  не пришел даже Петр.